# Can I install TypeScript definitions without using npm or typings in WebStorm/PhpStorm

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, phpstorm, webstorm

I just found that I can install TypeScript definitions in this settings:

[image]

which is convenient because I don't need to use `typings` or `npm` to install the types.

But what are the settings in `tsconfig.json` that make WebStorm use those definitions? Do these libraries downloaded in `webstorm` actually work?

I'm still getting `Cannot find module react` in `.tsx`

[image]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./src/",
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "src"
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "database",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mobx": "^3.1.0",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.0",
    "native-base": "^2.0.8",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.41.2",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-mobx": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-orientation": "^1.17.0",
    "react-native-pathjs-charts": "0.0.26",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.37.0",
    "react-native-sglistview": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-storage": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries configured in `Javascript| Libraries` are only used by PhpStorm itself for code completion/navigation, but they aren't available to TypeScript compiler service.
When you download Typescript stubs via `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Javascript | Libraries`, they are placed in `~/.PhpStorm*/config/javascript/extLibs/`. It's perfectly fine for PhpStorm, but the tsc compiler does need the `d.ts` files being placed somewhere in the project directory.
So, to get downloaded stubs available to Typescript compiler, you need to copy/move them to you project directory (and probably rename to more human readable names :)). They will be available to both PhpStorm and compiler then.
We plan to provide an option to download files directly to the project folder (instead of `system/extLibs/` ) in the future versions, please follow [WEB-9237](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9237) for updates. Related feature request: [WEB-14413](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14413)

So, it seems that using `npm` (`npm install @types/`) is the best solution if you need the typings to be available to TypeScript compiler

Answer (score 1):

You should use npm but if you insist on not doing it, I would suggest creating a `typings` directory with a sub directory made of the module name, itself containing the definition file

```
-typings
    -react
        react.d.ts
```

Simply make sure that the typings directory is part of the compilation path i.e. not `excluded` in `tsconfig.json`

The reasoning behind having them in you project is that these files contain versioned code, like the rest of your typescript files

When you change library version most likely the definition files will need to change as well to reflect new and deprecated features (and you do not want npm to manage it for you)